# Issue Eclipse Not Found ExternalContext as Resource

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat8

I had to switch from IntelliJ to Eclipse (Luna Version) and I had to upgrade old projet from java 1.6 to 1.8 also adding Maven to handle dependencies... 
When I run the project on IntelliJ under Tomcat (8.0.53), I have no issue at all. Everything is working smoothly.
When I start the application from Eclipse... I'm facing this issue :

> SEVERE: Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=500, location=/error500.faces]
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /myProject/pages/template_nobuttons.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource
>       at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.resolveURL(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:300)
>       at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.getRelativePath(DefaultFacelet.java:468)
>       at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:550)
>       at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:240)
>       at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:150)
>       at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:59)
>       at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:48)
>       at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:187)
>       at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.buildView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:483)
>       at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:79)
>       at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:266)
>       at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:716)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:468)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:442)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:301)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:396)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:176)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1152)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

I'm not particulary familier with Eclipse and I already tried several things after doing some research. But nothing seems to work... snifff :(

What is wierd is when I create a WAR file from Eclipse and run it manually from the tomcat instance deploying the ROOT.war ... Everything is working smoothly aswell.

So I assume it should be something in the configuration of Eclipse when I start the Tomcat Server from Eclipse ... Any idea would be appreciated

Here is a screen of my WebContent Folder 
[WebContent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsV1c.png)

I already put this in my web.xml

```
<context-param>
<param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
<param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried rebuild the project with maven goal "clean install", in my experiences, error like this often disapear after rebuild.

Comment: Yep, I already did that but it's not working ... package WAR working fine on the Tomcat Server but when I start Tomcat from Eclipse ... Still have the issue